# como puedo transformar un deb a ipa

Tags: python, ios, xcode

hola quisiera ver si me puede ayudar quisiera trasformar  un deb a ipa para instalarlo en el iphone sin jailbreak o tambiem haber si hay posibilidad abrir el deb en xcode e tratado de cargar el deb en la mac me da error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.